# Update React Navigation header title BEFORE render

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

When using React Navigation in React Native app, I need to set header title before actual render of screen. Is it possible? Setting params in `componentDidMount()` is too late.

Why I need it: I have one Component (Screen) for two same forms what have same content but are different in title and API call. So I do not want to make two Components with almost same code.

Comment: There is solution but for sometimes you have to display some default title or you can just display blank title.

Comment: Thats what I do not want to

Comment: Create one component and two screens. Use the same component on both screens. Set your navigation props for each screen as you wish and navigate between your screens when it's required.